# spaCy process document with multiple languages

Tags: python, data-structures, nlp, multilingual, spacy

Given a document string `s` of a certain length and a language mask `l` of the same length I would like to process each part (`span`?) of the document with the according spacy language model.

say for example

```
s = 'As one would say in German: Wie man auf englisch zu sagen pflegt'
l = ['en'] * 27 + ['de'] * 37
```

I would like to construct a document out of

```
import spacy
nlp_de = spacy.load('de')
nlp_en = spacy.load('en')

d_de = nlp_de(u"".join([c for i,c in enumerate(s) if l[i] == "de"]))
d_en = nlp_en(u"".join([c for i,c in enumerate(s) if l[i] == "en"]))
```

And now I would somehow have to glue that two parts together. But unfortunately, the document in spacy holds information about the vocabulary. This would thus be ambiguous.

How should I model my multi-language documents with spacy?

Comment: I believe spacy has a multilingual model that will handle english and german in one model. Check the list of models.

Comment: But based on spacy documentation the multilingual currently: "Wikipedia corpus. Assigns named entities. Supports identification of PER, LOC, ORG and MISC entities for Dutch, English, French, German, French, Italian, Polish, Portuguese, Russian and Spanish."

Answer (score 2):

2 thoughts regarding this:

1. [code switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching): which is the combination of more than 1 language into (mainly but not restricted to) spoken text. This is not exactly your example.
2. Sentences like yours, which are kind of separable.

If most of your text is more like your example, i would try to try and separate the text by languages (for your example i would yield 2 sentences and process each on its own).

If it's the other case, I'm not sure if spacy has built-in support for code-switch, and if not you'll need to build your own models (or just try to combine those of spacy) depends on your actual task

Comment: thank you for this answer. I will once again look into the spatial distribution of languages. I know that my data has around two-thirds german and one third french and just very few occurrences of other languages, but what I don't know is whether it is mostly inter-sentence or rather whole paragraphs in either language. For now, I will not mark this as an accepted answer since my question was more about how to use the spaCy data structures for this problem